# Einstein Bots - training

Tags: liveagent, einstein-analytics, servicecloud, einstein, chat

I'm working on a developer org and trying out the Einstein Bots feature for a possible implementation in a Sandbox/Prod environment. I create the dialogs and add the Einstein Intent phrases, but when I train the bot a generic error message shows and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong:

[image]

The procedure to replicate the error is as follows:

1) Create an Eintein Bot.

2) Create two Dialogs with a simple message.

3) Create 2 intent sets with 20-22 inputs and assign them to the Dialogs. Or add the inputs directly to the Dialogs.

4) Go to Overview and press the Train Bot button.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the self-signed certificate that was emailed to you when you enabled the bot? The training won't work without it

Answer (score 0):

You can solve creating a new Self Signed Certificate

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000272862&type=1

Answer (score 0):

Check out these few things you might not have done -
1. Signing up for Einstein Platform Services & Adding .PEM file?
2. Adding Remote Site URL - 'https://api.einstein.ai'
3. Self Signed Certificate creation & assignment?

Surely you are missing something..!!!